# Looking for a Synonym for Turntable

Tags: synonyms

Is there a more generic word, perhaps a term from math or engineering, that describes a disc that rotates about its centre, like a turntable?

Comment: So far all I've found is this interesting discussion of turntable physics: http://www.stereophile.com/content/turntable-physics-conundrum-1

Comment: Seriously, what you are describing is a rotating cylinder whose radius is many times its height (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29). From a physics perspective, there are many interesting types of rotating cylinder, such as the Tipler and the O'Neill. Disregard the similarity to names of condoms and look them up.

Comment: DJs refer to these as "decks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the simple "**rotor**". See the Wikipedia article on the multiple instances of usage of the term.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotor

Answer (score -2):

In engineering we call it a "Console". Hope it helps.

Comment: --References?--

Comment: CD Drives can be called consoles.  or Sony PS3 is called a console which is also a turn table.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_console

Comment: 'Console' really does push the bounds of polysemy. It was (and probably still is, by collectors) used to describe a free-standing radio (innards plus carcase, I believe) (and valve era) larger than a 'table-top' model.